# How to sort React components based on specific value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, jsx

I have React component. This components take 'units' - (array of objects) prop. Based on that I render component for each of item. I want to sort my components based on 'price' value, which is one of state items property. But when i trigger the sorting - state changes correctly but my components order not changing.

```
const SearchBoxes = ({units}) => {
    const [unitsState, setUnitsState] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        setUnitsState(units)
    }, [units])

    const sortByPrice = () => {
        const sortedUnits = sort(unitsState).desc(u => u.price); // sorting is correct
        setUnitsState(sortedUnits) // state is changing correctly
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {unitsState.map((u,i) => {
                return <UnitBox key={u.price} unit={u} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Can somebody help me, please ?
Why my components order do not changing when the state is changing after sort triggering ?

Comment: when I use 'i' (index) as a key value it do not works too.

Comment: What are `sort` and `desc`? You should use key values that are unique within your dataset. Can you get a running codesandbox up and share a link in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling sortByPrice anywhere--all you've done is to define the function.  I haven't tried it, but what if you changed useEffect to:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setUnitsState(sort(unitsState).desc(u => u.price));
}, [units])
```

Then you don't need the sort method at all.

Comment: It doesn't matter how I trigger this, it works fine, it changes state and the problem is that order of my components not changes based on state